# How to create common publish profile in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a solution with multiple projects. The `PublishSettings.targets` file is in the root.

[image]

**PublishSettings.targets**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <publishUrl>D:\inetpub\wwwroot\sctest5</publishUrl>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
      bin\roslyn\*;bin\Coveo.*.dll;bin\Newtonsoft.*.dll\Sitecore.WFFM.*;bin\*.pdb;*.config;bin\System.*.dll;bin\*.config;
      bin\Microsoft.*.dll;bin\Sitecore.Kernel.dll;bin\Sitecore.Mvc.dll;bin\DynamicPlaceholders.*.dll;bin\Newtonsoft.json.dll;bin\DynamicPlaceholders.dll;
    </ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>sourcefiles;raw-images;bin\App_Config\;bin\App_Config\Include\Social;</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now, in each project I would like to have a publish profile that would read from the `PublishSettings.targets` file, like this:

**Local.pubxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="..\..\..\..\..\..\..\PublishSettings.targets"/>
</Project>
```

So that, if the target publish folder needs to be changed, it can be done only at one place i.e `PublishSettings.targets`.

But, when I create this Local.pubxml in one of the projects and try to publish, seems it is not reading the global file.

[image]

I tried changing this part `"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\` by adding/removing levels, but it still doesn't work.

I was able to follow the same for previous projects using Visual Studio 2017.

How can I achieve this or is there a simpler alternative.

Comment: I am having the same issue in VS 2022. I noticed that you can create a targets file and that works with dotnet publish from the command line. However, the Visual Studio GUI will not show the profile.